# Filling column null fields with specific values from another column fields

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to pyspark, i need your help concerning dataframe column creation. I have a dataframe of type:

| FROM_CURRENCY | TO_CURRENCY | RATIO_FROM | RATIO_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED | EUR | 0 | 0 |
| AED | EUR | 1 | 1 |
| GNF | EUR | 0 | 0 |
| DZD | EUR | 1 | 1 |
| GNF | EUR | 1000 | 1000 |

I would like to create two additional columns: Ratio_FROM_BIS and Ratio_To BIS ( Based on values of FROM_CURRENCY and TO_CURRENCY), if you noticed, 0 values were replaced by non null values from other fields with same FROM_CURRENCY values.

| FROM_CURRENCY | TO_CURRENCY | RATIO_FROM_BIS | RATIO_TO_BIS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED | EUR | **1** | **1** |
| AED | EUR | **1** | **1** |
| GNF | EUR | **1000** | **1000** |
| DZD | EUR | 1 | 1 |
| GNF | EUR | **1000** | **1000** |

I have tried to used .withColumn(field1,F.Lit(command)) but it's not working.

Comment: are there 2 records for "DZD"? how did you get 1000 there?

Comment: I have modified the dataset, each currency may appear many times.

Comment: okay, if each currency can occur multiple times, will they have the same ratio value for all records (apart from the null ones)?

Comment: yes, for example AED can take only RATIO_FROM=1 and RATIO_TO=1, so if i find another AED with RATIO_FROM=0 i should replace it with 1 same for RATIO_TO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, there can be multiple records for a certain currency (`from_currency`) and all of the non-zero records will have the same ratio values. I've added the last row to denote this scenario.

An approach with `max()` window function.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd

data_ls = [
    ('AED', 'EUR', 0, 0),
    ('AED', 'EUR', 1, 1),
    ('GNF', 'EUR', 0, 0),
    ('DZD', 'EUR', 1, 1),
    ('GNF', 'EUR', 1000, 1000),
    ('GNF', 'EUR', 1000, 1000)
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    toDF(['from_curr', 'to_curr', 'ratio_to', 'ratio_from'])

# +---------+-------+--------+----------+
# |from_curr|to_curr|ratio_to|ratio_from|
# +---------+-------+--------+----------+
# |      AED|    EUR|       0|         0|
# |      AED|    EUR|       1|         1|
# |      GNF|    EUR|       0|         0|
# |      DZD|    EUR|       1|         1|
# |      GNF|    EUR|    1000|      1000|
# |      GNF|    EUR|    1000|      1000|
# +---------+-------+--------+----------+

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('ratio_to_bis',
               func.when(func.col('ratio_to') > 0, func.col('ratio_to')).
               otherwise(func.max('ratio_to').over(wd.partitionBy('from_curr', 'to_curr')))
               ). \
    withColumn('ratio_from_bis',
               func.when(func.col('ratio_from') > 0, func.col('ratio_from')).
               otherwise(func.max('ratio_from').over(wd.partitionBy('from_curr', 'to_curr')))
               ). \
    show()

# +---------+-------+--------+----------+------------+--------------+
# |from_curr|to_curr|ratio_to|ratio_from|ratio_to_bis|ratio_from_bis|
# +---------+-------+--------+----------+------------+--------------+
# |      DZD|    EUR|       1|         1|           1|             1|
# |      GNF|    EUR|       0|         0|        1000|          1000|
# |      GNF|    EUR|    1000|      1000|        1000|          1000|
# |      GNF|    EUR|    1000|      1000|        1000|          1000|
# |      AED|    EUR|       0|         0|           1|             1|
# |      AED|    EUR|       1|         1|           1|             1|
# +---------+-------+--------+----------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still returning the same values (Null values).

Comment: @f.ivy null or zeroes? your dataframe in the question (and comments) suggests they're zeroes

Comment: It's corking now i deleted the second group 'to_curr' from the window.partitionBY and it's replacing null values with right values thanks a lot !